# Transforming Data: R

Tags: r, transformation

I'm new to using R but need to use it for a school project. I am trying to run a one-way ANOVA test but I do not have homogeneity of variance for either of my two datasets. I am trying to transform the data to fix that. I have two datasets ("Secondary" and "Tertiary") with firm's revenue per employee (RperE) categorized by whether they belong to the secondary sector or tertiary sector.

Here's what I did so far:

```
p1 <- qplot(x = RperE, data = Tertiary)
p2 <- qplot(x = log10(RperE), data = Tertiary)
p3 <- qplot(x = sqrt(RperE), data = Tertiary)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)

pA <- qplot(x = RperE, data = Secondary)
pB <- qplot(x = log10(RperE), data = Secondary)
pC <- qplot(x = sqrt(RperE), data = Secondary)

grid.arrange(pA, pB, pC, ncol = 1)
```

How do I assign the transformed data to my datasets "Secondary" and "Tertiary" so I can re-run the Bartlett tests?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Questions about what you *should* do really depend on your data and what assumptions you want to make and what kind of conclusions you wish to make about your data. Those are statistical concern, not programming questions.

Comment: The first question is not a programming question, yes. The second question, "how do I assign the transformed data to my datasets "Secondary" and "Tertiary" so I can re-run the Bartlett tests?" is a programming question.

Comment: The please provide a reproducible example with sample input the the desired output so that possible solutions can be tested and verified. So you are just asking how to creat a new column that’s a transformation of an existing column? Have you done a transform() or dplyr::mutate() before? The plots don’t seem relevant in this case.

Comment: Yes, how do I transform my existing datasets using log?